# Lost wireless connection after OS continuously on for a week

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

Accessing wireless network usually works fine on my Ubuntu 10.10 on Lenovo T400. But sometimes,

1. Lost wireless connection after the OS having been on almost a week:

   When it happens like today, I
   cannot connect to a wireless
   network, although Network Manager
   can detect and show all available
   wireless networks. It is also strange
   that WICD cannot detect any
   available wireless networks either.
2. Lost wireless connection every few
   minutes:

   When this happens, the wireless network connection
   became lost after a few minutes. After manually trying to reconnect, it was
   able to connect again, although it
   got lost again  after another few minutes.

My system has been up for almost a week, and there have been various programs running including Firefox, Google Chrome, and HTTrack. Not sure these can be factors of the problem.

I was wondering why the problem happens and what I can try to solve the problem?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Running a linux machine for a week without reboot is nothing :) its like saying you had Windows running for 5 minutes. People go years without rebooting their linux box so you can rule that out. Yes I meant to type years. Did you have to reboot because of an update?

Comment: This is basic wireless network troubleshooting. You'll need to tell us more details: Has it ever worked? When did it stop working? What, if anything, changed immediately before it stopped working? How far are you from the AP? Are there items that could be causing interference (cordless phones, wireless speakers, microwave ovens)? Have you tried using different channels? Is your building made of brick, or does it have metal struts? Is your computer in a basement or attic? Have you tried swapping out the wireless adapter to see if it's a hardware problem?

Comment: @goblinbox: Yes, it used to work fine. Stop working several days, or a few hours after start. I open applications such as Firefox, documents, among others. Whenever the problem occurs, if I immediately restart, it will be fine again. I don't think other factors you mentioned are the reason.

Comment: Could be a failing wireless adapter. Or it could still be interference. Do you have another adapter you can try?